How to Manually Deploy an AWS Amplify App Connected to GitHub with Auto-Build Disabled?
I have a project hosted on AWS Amplify, which is connected to a specific branch on GitHub. Due to specific requirements, auto-build is disabled for this environment in Amplify. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to manually deploy latest updates to this Amplify app.
Here's the scenario:

The project is hosted on AWS Amplify.
It's connected to a specific branch on GitHub.
Auto-build is disabled for this environment in Amplify.
Note: I am not using GitHub Actions for deployment.

How can I manually trigger a deployment to this specific environment on AWS Amplify?
I've searched through the AWS Amplify documentation and various forums, but I couldn't find a clear solution tailored to this scenario.
